# How to reference every source in latex with brackets and numbers like [1]

Tags: bibtex

i would like to reference every source in my latex document with brackers [] and incrementing Numbers.

Everything works fine with the first Source.

```
@misc{doc:stz,
   author = "Thomas Nonnenmacher",
   title = "LaTeX Grundlagen - Setzen einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit
Skript",
    year = "2008",
    url = "http://www.stz-softwaretechnik.de",
    note = "(Bei STZ Internetseite unter Publikationen - Skripte) [V.\,2.0 26.02.08]"
}
```

This outputs -> [1] when i reference with \cite(doc:stz)

The next source

```
@misc{doc:gun,
    AUTHOR       = "Karsten Günther",
    TITLE        = "LaTeX2 --- Das umfassende Handbuch",
    PUBLISHER    = "Galileo Computing",
    YEAR         = "2004",
    url = "http://www.galileocomputing.de/katalog/buecher/titel/gp/titelID-768",
    SERIES       = "1. Auflage",
    VOLUME       = "",
    ADDRESS      = "",
    EDITION      = "",
    MONTH        = "",
    NOTE         = ""
}
```

outputs -> [Gun04] when i reference it with \cite(doc:gun)

I used this package \usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
but doesnt work

Thanks everyone for replying

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ahV5E8sy works fine for me. Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you type:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
```

Maybe you want, that the bibliography you reverence first is called 1 and the seccond is called 2 and so on. Normaly it is sorted automaticaly (not this way). If you want to do that type:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none}
```